# Cannot connect to MongoDB in docker

Tags: docker, mongodb

Using the official `mongo` image from the docker hub, I run the following command to get it running:

```
docker run --name api -p 127.0.0.1:27017:27017 -p 127.0.0.1:28017:28017 -d mongo
```

Then from another terminal shell, I run `mongo`

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.3
connecting to: test
2016-02-18T13:52:08.110-0700 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() errno:104 Connection reset by peer 127.0.0.1:27017
2016-02-18T13:52:08.110-0700 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:27017] 
2016-02-18T13:52:08.110-0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:224:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

I checked the logs for the container, and everything seemed right:

```
2016-02-18T20:51:20.538+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=73334e5089e1
2016-02-18T20:51:20.538+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.3
2016-02-18T20:51:20.538+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: b326ba837cf6f49d65c2f85e1b70f6f31ece7937
2016-02-18T20:51:20.538+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
2016-02-18T20:51:20.538+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-02-18T20:51:20.538+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-02-18T20:51:20.538+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-02-18T20:51:20.538+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian71
2016-02-18T20:51:20.538+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-02-18T20:51:20.538+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-02-18T20:51:20.538+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-02-18T20:51:20.542+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=8G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-02-18T20:51:20.615+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-02-18T20:51:20.615+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-02-18T20:51:20.615+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-02-18T20:51:20.615+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-02-18T20:51:20.615+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-02-18T20:51:20.615+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-02-18T20:51:20.615+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-02-18T20:51:20.616+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2016-02-18T20:51:20.616+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-02-18T20:51:20.633+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

What's wrong with docker or Mongo? I've searched everywhere for an answer, and nothing has worked so far. Is docker or Mongo broken?

**Edit:** 
I did a little more investigation, and I found that I cannot access the internet from inside the container. I connect to it by running `docker exec -ti api /bin/bash` and then try to ping google or something, and the command just hangs.

I can only seem to get an internet connection from the container to the outside world by using `--net=host` in the `docker run` command.

Comment: This may not help, but I noticed in the mongo client error message that it said `network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'`. Perhaps this is a permission error?

Comment: It turned out to be a docker networking issue with docker and my VPN client conflicting with each other.

Answer (score 7):

You have to tell the container to use it's own IP Address instead of localhost.

For example, let's assume you generated scaffold code with `expressjs`, you have to write in `routes/index.js`

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
router.get('/thelist', function(req, res){

  // Get a Mongo client to work with the Mongo server
  var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

  // Define where the MongoDB server is
  var url = 'mongodb://172.17.0.5:27017/dbname';

  // Connect to the server
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  .........
```

where `172.17.0.5` is the `$CONTAINER_IP`

you can find the container ip via

`$ docker inspect $CONTAINER_NAME | grep IPAddress`

### If no internet in container

Open with sudo `sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq`, so you would now have:

```
[main]                        
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq                  

[ifupdown]                    
managed=false
```

#### Edit: service name instead of IP

You may now use **service name** instead of IP Address of the container, eg:

```
  // Define where the MongoDB server is
  var url = 'mongodb://api:27017/dbname';
```

Comment: api:27017, uri scheme for the win...

Comment: What is a service name?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/tests/fixtures/v3-full/docker-compose.yml#L3) is a service name

Comment: How would you know that container IP ahead of time? Say, if you wanted to put this in a Dockerfile?

Comment: You don't. The IPs are assigned automatically by default from a class C range. You can a) get the IP after container is up via `docker inspect <container>`; or b) start a container with static IP address assigned - requires creating a `docker network`, there's alot on this over the Internet.

Answer (score 4):

The gotcha here is - if a *container* listens on 127.0.0.1, then the host can't map ports to it.

You need to listen on `0.0.0.0` or similar, and then the `-p` can reach the container's interface.

Comment: So you mean modify the `docker run` command to be `docker run --name mongo -p 0.0.0.0:27017:27017 -p 0.0.0.0:28017:28017 -d mongo` instead? If so, that doesn't change anything, I still cannot connect to the container using the mongo shell.

Comment: No. Change the mongo config so it doesn't listen to just loopback.

Comment: That didn't work, but what did work was disabling dnsmasq on the host.

Comment: this worked for me, I just commented the line `bindIp:` under the `net:` section, thank you !

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but found another way to address this issue. You can just pass network parameter while running docker image and this way docker points to correct localhost.

`docker run --network="host" ....`

[Source for this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)