# Cannot connect to MongoDB in docker on Windows host

Tags: networking, docker

I have a similar problem discussed in [Cannot connect to MongoDB in docker](https://serverfault.com/questions/758225/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-in-docker).

- Windows host
- Docker Toolbox, so it is using VirtualBox

I used `docker run --name mongo2 -p 127.0.0.1:27017:27017 mongo` to create the MongoDB container.

When I connect to the container (`docker -it mongo2 /bin/bash`), I can connect to Mongo via `mongo localhost:27017`.

I also checked with *netstat* that Mongo is listening on *0.0.0.0:27017*, not only localhost.

Still, I'm not able to connect from my Windows host to the container.
I even tried to disable Windows firewall and still nothing:

```
rs@ausus:~$ telnet localhost 27017
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem found & solved. When I opened the boot2docker VM, I saw that it is listening on 127.0.0.1:27017. So I created the container without specifying the interface, only "docker run --name mongo1 -p 27017:27017 mongo" and then the boot2docker VM was listening on all interfaces. Then I needed to get the address of the VM ("docker-machine env") and voila, from the Windows host PC I can "mongo 192.168.99.100:27017"

Answer (score 2):

*The answer is provided in the first comment actually (and it solved for me the same problem), but it is easier to find it when it is in the Answer section.*

The answer will assume that you're using Docker Toolbox.

---

Instead of running:

```
docker run --name mongo2 -p 127.0.0.1:27017:27017 mongo
```

the following command should be run:

```
docker run --name mongo2 -p <ip of boot2docker VM>:27017:27017 mongo
```

To get the `<ip of boot2docker VM>` VM:

1. Go to VirtualBox --> select "default" VM --> click "Show" button.
2. Run the command: `docker-machine env`.
3. The IP of the VM will be in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Like the Docker documentation says at https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/ :
"This means that it is not possible to run a MongoDB container with the data directory mapped to the host"

Finally I have done a `.bat` script that defines my Win10 IP and map it to a variable.
I run MongoDB directly on my Win10 and then access it with the IP.
That is not what I want but it works.

startup.bat :

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do set ip=%%b
set DOCKERHOST=%ip:~1%
docker-compose up
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
environment:
     - MONGO_HOST=${DOCKERHOST}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
host.docker.internal:27017
```

This is enabled on recent versions of Docker Desktop for Windows.

To test, you can also ping the Docker network interface:

```
C:\>ping host.docker.internal
Pinging host.docker.internal [192.168.0.2] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

Quote from [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/):

> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). We recommend that you connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Windows.

The "will not work in a production environment" sounds like a big downside, but if this Linux-based container is deployed to the cloud under Linux then the DNS name will change anyway, so it's a moot point.